# Is there away to programatically remove a store's product's attribute value without loading the whole product or using raw sql?

Tags: attributes, multistore, products

The slow way that works:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->load($productId)
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->setData($code , null)
            ->save();
```

I've seen:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->addAttributeUpdate($code, null , $storeId);
```

This however deletes the default value as well. (possible bug ?)

Other examples I have seen are raw mysql delete queries.

I though that this would be something native to Magento.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
    array($productId),  //array with product ids - works with multiple ids at the same time
    array($code=>null), //attributes to update - can update multiple attributes in one call 
    $storeId, //store to update. 0 = default values.
);
```

Comment: This works for updating a store value to a value, but not for setting it to use default